# Purging old data from a MongoDB collection to keep only a certain amount (not based on date)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my application I'm using MongoDB to store user documents and the edit history (revisions) of these documents.

I use two collections for this: `data` and `data_revisions`. Each time a user makes a change in a document from the `data` collection, the original document is copied over to the `data_revisions` collection and a reference to the original item in the `data` collection is added.

I am looking for a "best practice" solution for keeping only a specific amount of "revisions" in the `data_revisions` collection and purge old values. I want to keep e.g. max 5 records (regardless the date they were created).

I could select the last 5 items, check the creation date of the oldest one and then delete everything older, but is there perhaps a more elegant way of doing this?